# Add my own event to "Sent Events" in Interface Builder menu for my own custom UIView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uibutton

I have created a subclass of UIView and I would like to have it publish custom events that show up in Interface Builder (actually Xcode4) the same way that controls like UIButton have a bunch of events in the "Sent Events" area when you right click on a control in the Xcode 4 designer.  I know I can use Delegation (via Protocols) or Notification (via the UINotificationCenter) to let the objects using my custom view know when certain things happen, but I would like to know if the "The Target-Action Mechanism" (described in the Cocoa Fundamentals Guide) is appropriate/desirable/possible to use and be integrated with the Xcode designer.  Coming from a mostly .NET background, this approach seems to be closely related to the .NET event model and makes the most sense to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [UIControlEventApplicationReserved](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIControlEventApplicationReserved), which gives you a range of event identifiers that your app can use. However, I don't think there's any way to tell Interface Builder about application-defined events, so you won't get the same support for your events in IB as you find for UIControl's standard events. Instead, you'll have to specify the target and action for each app-defined event in code. (Please, someone correct me if I'm mistaken on this point.) That's not at all difficult, but it is a little different.

Comment: Ah, OK.  Having to provide the "target" seems a lot messier than just setting up a delegate, although I guess I could just have my custom UIView take it (via a property or method) as an NSObject so my view wouldn't have to include headers for objects that sit higher up in the app hierarchy and be tightly coupled.  My guess is that this is what happens when doing a connection in the designer, so it is probably the same thing.  It does seem like the standard or perhaps, preferred method is to just use Delegation.  I couldn't find much info on the aforementioned "Target-Action Mechanism".

Comment: They're very similar ideas. A view controller is often the target and/or delegate for the views and controls that it manages. In that case, it would just pass 'self' as the target and one of it's selectors as the action in a call to `-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`.

Comment: It's year `2022` but still not possible! at least not with `Swift 5` and `Catalyst`.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to do this is to extend `UIControl` instead of `UIView` this will allow you to add a target to all the default events (same as `UIButton` etc).

Note: in order for my custom `UIControl` to handle the events as opposed to the controls I layered on top of it I had to ensure that `userInteractionEnabled = NO` was set on all the layered controls.

Comment: It's the way to go !  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using an IBOutletCollection. The advantage of this approach is that you can link objects in Interface Builder. The downside is that you can't link directly to IBActions (like UIControl). Here is a clean implementation using a protocol:

ObserverProtocol.h

```
@protocol ObserverProtocol <NSObject>
- (void)observedObjectChanged:(id)sender;
@end
```

MyObject.h

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
{
@private
    IBOutletCollection(id<ObserverProtocol>) NSArray *observers;
}
- (void)objectChanged;
```

MyObject.m

```
@implementation MyObject

- (void)objectChanged
{
    for (id<ObserverProtocol> observer in observers)
    {
        if ([observer respondsToSelector:@selector(observedObjectChanged:)])
        {
            [observer observedObjectChanged:self];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Then you just need to implement ObserverProtocol in classes you want to observe the event (and to do the binding in Interface Builder of course).